# How do I uninstall applications on my Mac?

Tags: macos, mac, uninstall

I understand that uninstalling applications on Mac requires moving only the `.app` bundle to the Trash; or **manually** rummaging through the preferences and application support files for the more non-bundle complicated applications. The **manually** part is surely a tedious thing to do.

Can you suggest something like CCleaner for Mac? What are good free applications that can do the job?

Comment: You could also consider leaving out the second part entirely except maybe large Application Support directories, see e.g. [here](http://superuser.com/questions/34314/do-i-need-to-bother-about-correctly-uninstalling-mac-software) or [here](http://superuser.com/questions/177206/cleaning-up-mac-os-x/).

Comment: Duplicate: http://superuser.com/questions/92504/uninstall-on-mac-os-x

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use [TrashMe](http://www.jibapps.com/products/trashme/) to uninstall applications, plug-ins, and preference panes. It can also search for files that are left over from other installations/uninstalls. It is free as well.

Comment: It is not free now.

Answer (score 4):

Personally, I use [Appcleaner](http://www.freemacsoft.net/AppCleaner/), which does what you're looking for.  I've been using it for about a year and it does a decent job.  It will also all you to uninstall dashboard widgets as well.  It's free. Give it a look.

Answer (score 1):

While not free, [AppZapper](http://www.appzapper.com/) is the tool i've always recommended. The extra functionality of license management and an almost Add/Remove Programs like view is often times nice for switchers.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this article](http://www.myappleguide.com/blogs/iphone-world/2879/showdown-appcleaner-vs-appdelete-vs-appzapper-vs-cleanapp)…

…while [AppCleaner](http://www.apple.com/downloads/macosx/system_disk_utilities/appcleaner.html) will get the job done usually, it's basically a clone of [AppZapper](http://www.appzapper.com/). The best option is [AppDelete](http://www.apple.com/downloads/macosx/system_disk_utilities/appdelete.html).

Personally I use both AppCleaner and AppDelete and usually I find that one or the other works better for a given application.